# Excel Interop worksheet HRESULT: 0x800A03EC using VB.net

Tags: vb.net, excel, office-interop, hresult

so in my vb.net application, I am pulling data (about 1046 rows in the table) from database to pre-load the contents in excel spreadsheet. This works fine until 999 rows, but if it exceeds more than 999 rows it gives me that particular error. 
Just wondering if there is a restriction. Any ideas? I am using windows 10, management studio 2012 and excel 2007.

Code:

```
Private Sub readEmployee(ByVal employee As data.employeeList)

            Dim excelWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet 
            Dim startRow As Integer = 9
            Dim firstNames As String = ""
            Dim lastNames As String = ""              

            With excelWorkSheet  
                startRow = 9
                Dim row As data.employeeList.employeeListRow
                For Each row In employee.employeeList
                    If row.RowState <> DataRowState.Deleted Then

                        firstNames = CStr(IIf(row.FirstName.Trim() = "", "", row.FirstName.Trim()))
                        lastNames = CStr(IIf(row.LastName.Trim() = "", "", row.LastName.Trim()))

                        .Range("A" + startRow.ToString("n0")).Value = lastNames
                        .Range("B" + startRow.ToString("n0")).Value = firstNames          
                        startRow += 1
                    End If
                Next
            End With
    End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post entire error message and also what what line of code you are getting the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when startRow=1000,

`startRow.ToString("n0")` returns 1,000. That's incorrect format for `Range` parameter.

You don't need to use, `FormatProvider` for `ToString` here. Just use the default overload.

```
startRow.ToString()
```

is all you need.